# Method construction in perl

Tags: perl, function, subroutine

I'm really confused on how to make a method in perl.  What I would like to do is have a method say
printdoc(%hash).  I want to be able to call printdoc(%myhash) and then it use what's in the method to print the information then go back to my code. My use here is that I have several hashes I want to print a certain same way, but instead of having to copy paste the code over an over I would like to just be able to call it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [`sub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) keyword:

```
sub printdoc {
  my %hash = shift;
  # do whatever
}

printdoc(%hash)
```

However, this is suboptimal because `%hash` will be copied. Rather, passing a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) is better:

```
sub printdoc {
  my $hash_ref = shift;
  my %hash = %$hash_ref;
  # do whatever
}

printdoc(\%hash);
```

By the way, this is called a "subroutine" or a "function". A "method" is specifically a function on an object - no wonder you were just getting the object-oriented answers. :)

Comment: which one passes the reference because that is what I want to do.  what does the %$hash do and what does the \before %hash do?  And yeah that is probably why.  I will take a look at subroutine. :) ty for your help.

Comment: I linked the perlref page as well - that's where you learn about references. `\%hash` gets a reference to `%hash`, `%$hash_ref` looks up the reference and returns a full hash. (note I had an error, it said `%$hash` but should be `%$hash_ref`)